# How to parse YAML response body to POJO in Retrofit library?

Tags: android, kotlin, yaml, retrofit

I have a problem with handling responses in YAML format in Retrofit. Until now I only handled the response body in JSON format or plain text. For these types, I always have prepared converters like gson, jackson for JSON and scalars for plain text. I found repository with all converters: [retrofit-convertes](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters).
In the documentation is a short mention that I need to create my own converter for this type.

> If you need to communicate with an API that uses a content-format that Retrofit does not support out of the box (e.g. YAML, txt, custom format) or you wish to use a different library to implement an existing format, you can easily create your own converter. Create a class that extends the Converter.Factory class and pass in an instance when building your adapter.

Sadly, I don't see any tutorial on how to create such a converter. Is there any documentation explaining how to do this or is there any other option to handle such a case?

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can use Jackon with yaml data formats.

```kotlin
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
  .baseUrl("<your base url>")
  .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory())))
  .build();
```

For more informating check the following links:

https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/jackson

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/yaml